# How does local Spring app access mysql on OpenShift?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, javabeans, portforwarding

I am building a local Spring app to access the database I created on OpenShift at `127.2.xx.yy/eetom:3306`.  So I created this propery in `Beans.xml`.

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.2.xx.yy:3306/eetom"/>
```

but I got exceptions such as

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

and

```
The driver has not received any packets from the server
```

So I changed the ip to `localhost` and used OpenShift rhc to create port forwarding. And the `rhc` showed that the ip I put originally and the port are exactly used for port forwarding. That method workded.

### Question:

What is the right way to access the mysql diectly without port forwarding?

Comment: Look at this link http://javaseee.blogspot.ru/2013/03/deploying-tomcat-and-mysql-application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me on this before, it's from OpenShift:  OpenShift does not support direct connectivity to an embedded database on non-scalable applications.